# MPAndroidChart: How to hide chart background?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) v2.0.8. I can modify the background just outside the barchart but inside, there is still a grey background and I don't know which method I can use.

```
barchart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
barchart.setBackgroundColor(getRessouces().getColor(R.color.default_color));
```

I have this result :

[image]

I would like the default color into the chart too.

Thanks a lot,

Kamel

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [documentation.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started)

You can remove or modify the background behind the "drawing-area" with these two methods:

- `setDrawGridBackground(boolean enabled)`: If enabled, the background rectangle behind the chart drawing-area will be drawn.
- `setGridBackgroundColor(int color)`: Sets the color the grid-background should be drawn with.